# How to create a pipeline and perform copy activity in Azure data factory for the tables related to foreign keys?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am new to the Azure data factory and looking to copy CSV data into my table having a foreign key relationship.
 Here are my tables:

**Customer table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- Primary Key column
    [CustomerNumber] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] datetime,
    [CreatedBy] NVARCHAR(255),
    [ModifiedOn] datetime,
    [ModifiedBy] NVARCHAR(255)
);
GO

-- Insert rows into table 'Customer' in schema '[dbo]'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer]
VALUES
( 
 NEWID(),'Tom123', 'Tom', 'Shehu',GETDATE(),'test',GETDATE(),'admin'
),
( 
 NEWID(),'Harol234', 'Harold', 'Haoxa',GETDATE(),'test',GETDATE(),'admin'
),
( 
 NEWID(),'Peter345', 'Peter', 'Begu',GETDATE(),'test',GETDATE(),'admin'
),
( 
 NEWID(),'Marlin09', 'Marlin', 'Hysi',GETDATE(),'test',GETDATE(),'admin'
)

GO
```

**Product Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- Primary Key column
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [ErpNumber] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] datetime,
    [CreatedBy] NVARCHAR(255),
    [ModifiedOn] datetime,
    [ModifiedBy] NVARCHAR(255)
);
GO

-- Insert rows into table 'Product' in schema '[dbo]'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product]
VALUES
( 
 NEWID(), 'EI500CMZ', 'EI500CMZ','7-Day test product',GETDATE(),'Tom',GETDATE(),'Tom'
),
( 
 NEWID(), 'ST0SMX', 'ST0SMX','7-Day heavy duty product',GETDATE(),'Tom',GETDATE(),'Tom'
),
( 
 NEWID(), 'EH30MZ', 'EH30MZ','Electronic water test product',GETDATE(),'Tom',GETDATE(),'Tom'
)
```

**CustomerProduct**  table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerProduct]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- Primary Key column
    [CustomerId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] datetime,
    FOREIGN KEY(CustomerId) REFERENCES Customer(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY(ProductId) REFERENCES Product(Id)

);
GO
```

**Below is my CSV file data**:
**CustomerNumber,ErpNumber,Name** 
Tom123,EI500CMZ,EI500CMZ2340
Harol234,ST0SMX,ST0SMX74770
Peter345,EH30MZ,EH30MZ00234

Now I am looking to insert data into my 3rd table i.e CustomerProduct but I am not understanding how that "CustomerId", "ProductId" and "Name" will get inserted.
In the above CSV data, I am getting the "CustomerNumber" and "ErpNumber" but during the insertion "CustomerId" and "ProductId" should go in the table.

Not understanding how to do this.

So far I have done this in the Azure data factory:

1. Created a blob storage account. Added a container in blob storage and uploaded my CSV file.
2. Created a linked service of type Azure blob storage called "CustomerProductInputService" that will talk to blob storage
3. Created a linked service of type Azure SQL database called "CustomerProductOutputService" that will communicate with the "CustomerProduct" table.
4. Created a dataset of type azure blob. This will receive the data from "CustomerProductInputService".
5. Created a dataset of type azure SQL database.

Now I am stuck at copy activity. I am not understanding how to create pipeline for this scenario and insert data into the CustomerProduct table.
As I explained I am getting "CustomerNumber" and "ErpNumber" in the CSV file but I want to insert "CustomerId" and "ProductId" into my "CustomerProduct" table.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/515679/azure-data-factory-copy-activity-need-reference-of.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for this link, I will check the link. If I talk in simple C# language then I will do something like this:
foreach (DataRow item in csvData.Rows)
                {
                    string customerNumber = item["CustomerNumber"]
                        .ToString();
                    Guid customerId = customerTable
                        .Where(customer => customer.CustomerNumber == customerNumber)
                        .Select(customer => customer.Id)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
//Same I will do to get the product Id

                }

Comment: @ray Do I need a data flow in my scenario?

Comment: Yes, I believe you will need a dataflow for your scenario. I think solely using dynamic content to manipulate the output from lookup activity is unlikely to achieve the join by customerNumber behaviour that you want to achieve. Even if it is feasible, I believe it would be hard to maintain the dynamic content in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Insert the CustomerProduct data from CSV to the table using **dataflow** activity using **lookup** **transformations** to get the *CustomerID* and *ProductID* from Customer and Product table respectively.

[image]

**Source:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. **Add 3 source transformations in dataflow**, 1 for CSV source file, 1 for Customer table, and 1 for Product table.

a)  **Source1 (CSV)**: Create and **CSV dataset** to source1 to get Input file data.

[image]

b)  **Source2 (CustomerTable)**: Connect to **Customer table** and get all the existing data from the Customer table.

[image]

•   As we only need **ID and CustomerNumber columns** from the Customer table, add `select` transformation (Customer) after source2 to select only the required column list.

[image]

[image]

c)  Source3 (ProductTable): Connect Source3 to **Product Table** to pull all the existing data from dbo.Product.

[image]

[image]

•   Add `Select` transformation (Product) after Source3 to get only the required columns **ID & ERPNumber** from the column list.

[image]

2. Add `Lookup` transformation to `Source1` (CSV) with **Primary stream as CSV** source and **Lookup Stream as Customer** (Source2 Select transformation) and Lookup Condition as CSV column **“CustomerNumber” equals to (==) Customer table Column “CustomerNumber”**.

[image]

[image]

3. As `Lookup` is like Left join here, it includes all columns from Source1 and Lookup columns from Source2 in the select list (which include duplicate columns).

a)  So, using `select` transformation (CustomerSelectList) to select only the required columns in the Output. Also renaming the Column name “**ID**” which is pulled from Customer table to **CustomerID** to match with **Sink** table.

[image]

[image]

4. Add another `Lookup` transformation after Select (CustomerSelectList) to get the data from **Product table**.

a)  Select **Primary stream as CustomerSelectList** (Select transformation) and **Lookup stream as Product** (Select of Source3)

[image]

b)  With Lookup condition as **CSV Source column “ErpNumber” equals to (==) Product table column “ErpNumber”**.

[image]

[image]

5. Again, using the `select` transformation to ignore other columns and select only required columns from the select list. Also renaming column “**ID**” from Product table to **ProductID**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

6. Add `Derived Column` transformation to the select (CustomerProductSelectList) to add new columns **ID and CreatedOn**.

a)  **ID**: as this is **UNIQUEIDENTIFIER** in the sink table, we can add an expression to generate the id using **`UUID()`** in the derived column.

b)  **CreatedOn**: adding expression to get the `**Current timestamp**` to Sink table.

[image]

[image]

7. Finally add `Sink` transformation to Insert data onto **CustomerProduct** table.

[image]

[image]

[image]

8. Add this dataflow to a pipeline and run the pipeline to insert data.

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Since I am new to ADF, this gone be a good learning experience for me and it will help me to solve the problem. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

First thing you would need to identify a key connection between customer and product. Next, create a pipeline from data factory and create 2 sources "Product" and "Customer" apply ADF transformation Join and Alter and sink it to dbo.CustomerProduct.